# Including uncovered files in Devel::Cover reports

Tags: perl, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have a project setup like this:

```
bin/fizzbuzz-game.pl
lib/FizzBuzz.pm
test/TestFizzBuzz.pm
test/TestFizzBuzz.t
```

When I run coverage on this, using

```
perl -MDevel::Cover=-db,/tmp/cover_db test/*.t
```

... I get the following output:

```
----------------------------------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
File                                  stmt   bran   cond    sub   time  total
----------------------------------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
lib/FizzBuzz.pm                      100.0  100.0    n/a  100.0    1.4  100.0
test/TestFizzBuzz.pm                 100.0    n/a    n/a  100.0   97.9  100.0
test/TestFizzBuzz.t                  100.0    n/a    n/a  100.0    0.7  100.0
Total                                100.0  100.0    n/a  100.0  100.0  100.0
----------------------------------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
```

That is: the totally-uncovered file bin/fizzbuzz-game.pl is not included in the results.

How do I fix this?

Comment: (Not exactly the same, but for others who find this via Google) In a similar situation, I added [Test::UseAllModules](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::UseAllModules) to pull in all my lib/**/*.pm files.  That way `cover -test` knew about all of them, including those not otherwise tested.  [This article](https://www.perl.com/article/208/2016/1/5/Save-time-with-compile-tests/) by David Farrell shows how to pull in other files based on globs.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the documentation?  The section on [Selecting which files to cover](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-Cover/lib/Devel/Cover.pm#SELECTING_FILES_TO_COVER) seems most helpful. :)  It looks like the `+select` option is the one you are looking for.

Comment: I think that this option comes to play too late, eg. the system has a list of all files that were touched during the execution and then selects/ignores from that list. The problem is that untouched files are absent.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a work-around for this.

The core of this problem is that the uncovered code in the main file (fizzbuzz-game.pl) is not included in the coverage report, hence the overall percentage is wrong. The underlying problem is that substantial logic resides in the main file instead of testable modules. **This is a smell** (don't know which, but I'm pretty sure there is a name for "lots of logic in main()").

By getting rid of this smell, eg. moving all substatial code from bin/fizzbuzz-game.pl to lib/FizzBuzzGame.pm, the code can theoretically be tested, and can definitively be included in the test run.

The coverage report after this becomes:

```
----------------------------------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
File                                  stmt   bran   cond    sub   time  total
----------------------------------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
lib/FizzBuzz.pm                      100.0  100.0    n/a  100.0    0.0  100.0
lib/FizzBuzzGame.pm                   75.0    n/a    n/a   75.0  100.0   75.0
Total                                 87.5  100.0    n/a   83.3  100.0   88.9
----------------------------------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
```